# Convergence of series of series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This question may be a duplicate: I don't know how to ask google. The question I am asking came to me while studying the basics of measure theory. It is about the possibility of rearranging a series in whichever way you want. Let $A = \{ x_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable set of positive real numbers. We have that $$S = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x_k \in [0,  +\infty].$$ Now let $A_i, i \in \{ 1, \ldots, t\}, t \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{+\infty\}$ be a collection of non empty, pairwise disjoint, subsets of $A$. Let $\#A = R_i \in [1, +\infty]$. I want to show that $$S = \sum_{i = 1}^{t}(\sum_{k = 1}^{R_i}x_{i_k}).$$ If everything is finite this is obvious. Also, it is possible to assume that $\sum_{k = 1}^{R_i}x_{i_k} < +\infty$ for every $k$ (otherwise the fact is true in some way, with operations on the extended real line). I am looking for some interesting proof, or for reference.

Comment: Look for absolute convergence, Riemann reordering, Steinitz (ripping off Grassmann)

Comment: I have written that the terms are positive. And what exactly do you mean with Steinitz (ripping off Grassman)?

Comment: I'm just too lazy to look for the correct translation. In German it is "Riemanns großer Umordnungssatz", Riemanns main reordering theorem.  Stating that under absolute convergence, which you assume, any permutation of the order of terms leaves the value of the series unchanged.

Comment: As far as I know the Riemann series theorem states that if a series does converge, but not converge absolutely, you can find a permutation of the terms that make it converge to any real number. As far as I learned Dirichlet has proven the converse: that if a series does converge uniformly, you can rearrange the term as you like. But is my question equivalent to rearranging terms? I am calculating a countable number of series and then summing them up. If the single pieces where not series, I suppose it would have been equivalent to rearranging the whole sequence.

Comment: That's why this is comments and not an answer. Now we know that the question relates to the situation of an infinite decomposition with all parts infinite. But again, is that not similar to the situation of the Cauchy product of series?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the definition of series as the limit of the sequence of partial sums? i.e. looking at $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} x_k \le \sum_{i = 1}^{t}(\sum_{k = 1}^{R_i}x_{i_k}) \forall n$ and similarly the other inequality sign.

Comment: Yes, this seems to settle the thing easily! :) thank you!